# How to mock an Angular sub module that utilizes dependencies of the parent module?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Simple parent module

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'app.services']);
```

Simple sub module

```
angular.module('app.services');
```

We have access to `ngRoute` in this service because it is a dependency of `app.servies` which is a dependency of `app`.

```
angular.module('app.services').factory('myService', function($route) {
  // used $route in here
});
```

When testing the service with `jasmine`, what is the best way to mock the `app.services` module so that I have access to `$route`?

The best way I can think of is this:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  module('app');
  module('app.services');
});
```

But it would be better to just inject `ngRoute` without having to mock the `app` module.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this problem? I am facing a similar problem.

Comment: Did you try `$provide.value('ngRoute', myRouteMock)`?